# UILabel out of app frame

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiscrollview, uilabel

**my lables is out of the app frame:**

[image]

**only when im scrolling i can see the rest:**

[image]

```
    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 600)];

    self.description = [_description stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    [self positionLabel:self.lblTitle withText:self.stitle withY:10];
    [self positionLabel:self.lblPubDate withText:self.pubDate withY:CGRectGetMaxY(self.lblTitle.frame)+10 ];
    [self positionLabel:self.lblDescription withText:self.description withY:CGRectGetMaxY(self.lblPubDate.frame)+10 ];

}

-(void)positionLabel:(UILabel*)lbl withText:(NSString*)text withY:(CGFloat)Y
{
    lbl.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
    lbl.text = text;
    lbl.numberOfLines = 0;
    lbl.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    CGSize size = [self calculateSize:lbl];
    //FIXED
    [lbl setFrame:CGRectMake(10 , Y , (size.width>300)?size.width:300 , size.height)];
    [_scroller addSubview:lbl];
}



-(CGSize)calculateSize:(UILabel*)lbl
{
    CGSize size = [lbl.text sizeWithFont:lbl.font
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(280, MAXFLOAT)
                           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return size;
}
```

what could cauase that problem?
the labels in the xib may be related?

Comment: what is y cordinate of your scrollview ?

Comment: where can i see that?

Comment: You can see in your XIB.

Comment: in Size inspector --> View  i can see that the Y = 0

Comment: Just please set y coordinate of scrollview is 64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting `y co-ordinate` of your scrollView properly so Just set proper scrollView frame.

After adding your scrollView as subView just set its frame.

```
CGRect frame = yourScollView.frame;

frame.origin.y= frame.origin.y + 49; //49 is your navigationBar height.

[yourScollView setFrame:yourScollView.frame];
```

Comment: you are doing nice, just check your scrollView's frame

Comment: how you are making your scrollView

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28461/discussion-between-rajneesh071-and-oshrialm)

Comment: you have to set your scrollview frame initially